# accessing Activity members from onAreaTouched() in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm an AndEngine newbie, and right now im trying to figure the basics.

One of the things i'd like to know: How do i access members of the main BaseGameActivity from an overriden onAreaTouched of an Sprite? The thing is i don't think i can include a reference to the main activity in the call, because this method with this signature is what the engine will call by default.

Say i had an OnScreen DPad, how would i access my character sprite from the onAreaTouched() method of the dpad element?

Answer (score 0):

I pass a reference of the game activity to any object in my game which needs it, then I'm able to access the activity members. Just make sure you don't keep any reference which might be alive after the activity object dies (To avoid leaks).